# Why haproxy/rabbitmq consumers are stuck occasionally?

Tags: rabbitmq, haproxy

Need help and/or ideas regarding the combo: haproxy + rabbitmq.

**Topology**:

- cluster of 3 rabbitmq brokers, replication policy for queues { ha-mode: all }
- java apps with business logic are running on few nodes
- haproxy is running on the same node with every java app above, proxying to the rabbitmq cluster
- messages flowing between java apps count in hundred thousands a day per queue, number of queues is around 20

**Problem**:

- occasionally, once in few days, messages pile up in the queues and consumers on the java side appear to be idle or stuck
- restart of haproxy fixes the issue, consumers reconnect, resume and eventually empty the queues successfully

**Notes**:

- there are not errors in the logs, I have set the ExceptionHandler and do log everything thouroghly

**Question**:

- what could be a root cause of this problem?

haproxy.cfg:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local1
    maxconn 4096
    daemon
    user haproxy
    group haproxy

defaults
    timeout client 50000
    timeout server 50000
    timeout connect 5000
    log global
    mode tcp
    retries 3
    maxconn 2000
    option redispatch
    option tcplog

listen ampq
    bind *:5672
    mode tcp
    balance leastconn
    timeout client 3h
    timeout server 3h
    stick match src
    stick-table type ip size 200k expire 30m
    option clitcpka
    server rabbit1 10.6.1.1:5672 check inter 1s rise 3 fall 1
    server rabbit2 10.6.1.2:5672 check inter 1s rise 3 fall 1
    server rabbit3 10.6.1.3:5672 check inter 1s rise 3 fall 1
```

Comment: Hard to say, but `messages pile up in the queues and consumers on the java side appear to be idle or stuck` actually goes the other way around - messages are piling up because the consumers are slow, dead etc https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2014/04/14/finding-bottlenecks-with-rabbitmq-3-3/

Comment: We tend to believe consumers are dead because the connection through haproxy is not healthy for whatever reason. Publishers are already done when the problem is detected. Messages are just sitting in the queues and do not go through to the consumers.

Comment: @Andrey.Kozyrev Have you found any solution to this issue, because I seem to have found the same circumstances for this to happen?